# VMWare - NAS - Setup

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-attached-storage, synology

We're a new company, setting up infrastructure to support our service arm.  For this project we have ..

- Three hypervisors running ESXi 5.5.0
- A Synology NAS device.
- Permission to do what needs to be done.

The windows guy is setting up, as vmware guests, active directory, terminal services and related bits.  The NAS device is there to store data that will be written by end users, the processing applications.

I can deploy DFS onto a pair of Server 2012 guests, but is there a VMWare-specific method of deploying storage for [servers, terminal services, users]?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Deploy it as you would with physical servers. The only difference being that the HDD's for the VM's are actually VMDK files in your vSphere datastore. As an aside, are you using the Synology as a datastore for the vSphere hosts via NFS or iSCSI?

Comment: We are not.  I've been mulling that over.

The hypervisors are repurposed from a prior life as Xen hypervisors: in that role the guests had minimal 'local' drives, and did most of their data mangling on the Synology NAS via NFS.

So they have 'enough' local disk storage for boot disk / VMDK files.

I'm aware that, someday, we'll need to move away from this model, if we grow our vmware farm, and expand.  By that point we'll probably also outgrow the Synology drives and move to a more Enterprisey NAS.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?  And flesh out the detail?  How many users, how much data, are you using local disks on the ESXi boxes, what model NAS etc...